# Time complexity O() of two two part functions

Tags: f#

What would the time complexity be of these two algorithms?

```
let rec fol f a = function
      | []    -> a
      | x::xs -> fol f (f a x) xs;;

let mergelist xs = List.fol (@) [] xs
```

and

```
let rec folB f xs a =
      match xs with
      | []    -> a
      | y::ys -> f y (folB f ys a);;

let mergelist2 xs = List.folB (@) xs []
```

and how would i be able to test it my self?

Should return something like

```
mergelist [[1;2];[];[3];[4;5;6]];;
  val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

Comment: this is obviously homework right? First question: time-complexity in what? Length of the list? .. Also you want to know the complexity of `mergelist`/`mergelist2` right? ... What do you expect? Maybe it helps if you write down the evaluation for a small example list....

Comment: Every time you call `(@)` it takes `O(n)` where `n` the length of the list you are appending to.

Comment: **hint** what do you know about `@`? Is it's complexity dependent on the length of the first or the second list you give it? ... What direction would you expect to behave better then?

Comment: I was kind of hoping there was a function that had a counter for every time it looped through. I kind of feel like Megelist is N^K where N is the length of the list and K is the lists being added. While Mergelist2 is just NK

Comment: you can write such a function if you want: declare a mutable (ref) and use a version of `::` and `@` that will increment this variable - then run your merge and check it ... but still you can do it on paper (and you might learn more by it)

Comment: What's your reasoning behind N^K? You can test your assumption by trying your algorithm with N=10 and K=80. If you get an answer within your lifetime, then it wasn't N^K.

Comment: if you start with `mergelist`: how many times will you prepend the first `x` to something? ... this will lead to something like `n_1*m + n_2*(m-1) + ...` so you might want to assume `n := max n_i`  and then go with `n*(m+(m-1)+...)` ... where does this lead to? (more like `^2` ...)

Comment: It looks like it would have to go through all the elements of the list N to add the lists K for every extra list that exists

Comment: right ... now what about `mergelist2`? (hint: there will be no `^2` this time)

Comment: Mergelist2 wouldnt have that problem because it starts off with an empty list. Thats why i thought NK.

Comment: but really to make your life easier assume you have `m` lists of length `n` you want to concatenate with `mergelist(2)`

Comment: it's not because it starts of with the empty list - it's because it only prepends each list once instead of multiple times! (you assume right - of course you should *proof* it)

Comment: So the first mergelist has to go through it self N times (m+(m-1)...+0) to add the last element to its list: N*N. Merge2 does not have this problem because folB simply adds the entirety of the tail per every m. So MN.

Comment: not `n*n` - `m+(m-1)+ ...+0 = m*(m+1)/2` ;) (it's `O(nm^2)`)

Comment: Thanks for being so patient. I'm trying to wrap my head around this. It's just a little weird thinking in functional programming atm.

Comment: to be honest: it's more math then FP at this point ^^

Comment: than* I know. I really do appreciate it. I couldn't figure out what the function was doing which was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick&dirty snippet of how you can compare the two operations with `n` lists of length `3` each:

```
let rec fol f a = function
      | []    -> a
      | x::xs -> fol f (f a x) xs;;

let rec folB f xs a =
      match xs with
      | []    -> a
      | y::ys -> f y (folB f ys a);;

let compareThemFor n =
    let testList = List.replicate n [1;2;3]
    let count = ref 0

    let myCons x xs =
        incr count
        x :: xs

    let myApp ys =
        List.foldBack myCons ys

    let mergelist = fol myApp []
    mergelist testList |> ignore
    let countA = !count

    count := 0
    let mergelist2 xs = folB myApp xs []
    mergelist2 testList |> ignore
    let countB = !count

    (countA, countB)
```

and this is what you will get:

```
> compareThemFor 2;;
val it : int * int = (3, 6)
> compareThemFor 3;;
val it : int * int = (9, 9)
> compareThemFor 4;;
val it : int * int = (18, 12)
> compareThemFor 5;;
val it : int * int = (30, 15)
> compareThemFor 6;;
val it : int * int = (45, 18)
```

as you can see the second is far better and I hope the comments above helps you understand why.

Just in case here is the `n=3` version for `mergelist`:

```
mergelist [[1;2;3];[3;4;5];[6;7;8]]
{ second case in `fol` with `x=[1;2;3]` and `xs=[[3;4;5];[6;7;8]]` }
= fol (@) ([] @ [1;2;3]) [[3;4;5];[6;7;8]] // one @ of 0 elements = 0 operations
{ second case in `fol` with `x=[3;4;5]` and `xs=[[6;7;8]]` }
= fol (@) ([1;2;3] @ [3;4;5]) [[6;7;8]] // one @ of 3 elements = 3 operations
{ second case in `fol` with `x=[6;7;8]` and `xs=[]` }
= fol (@) ([1;2;3;3;4;5] @ [6;7;8]) [] // one @ of 6 elements = 6 operations
{ first case }
= [1;2;3;3;4;5;6;7;8] // 0+3+(3+3)=9 Operations Total
```

please note that you prepend `[1,2,3]` multiple times ...

Comment: Good approach, but your implementation of `mergeList2` wrongly uses `myCons` instead of `myApp`, skewing the results dramatically (though the ultimate conclusion is the same).

Comment: @supercell in case you wonder the first few are *worse*  because you add the very-last list too ...

Comment: @supercell also *fun*-fact - note how the first numbers increase exactly by the second? (3+6=9, 9+9=18, 18+12=30,...)

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. I have a test coming up in a month and this is a great resource.